# How to change width of flutter_svg image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package to use SVG images in my project.

```dart
SvgPicture.asset(
  image,
  semanticsLabel: name,
  height: 300,
  width: 100,
)
```

The above code displays SVG image with `height` of 300 but `width` does not change. Height is responding to the value changes but there is no effect on width. The above `SvgPicture` is a child of `Card`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap with SizedBox

```
        SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: 100,
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            image,
            semanticsLabel: name,
          ),
        )
```